# Order being ignored by Rails with comma gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following call using `comma` gem:

```
def by_location_csv
  @inventory_items=InventoryItem.where('location_id=? and is_deleted=false',params[:location_id]).order(:bin_number)
  render :csv => @inventory_items
end
```

but the order is ignored with this in the log:

```
Scoped order and limit are ignored, it's forced to be batch order and batch size
```

Is there any workaroud to this? can I pass in an option to up the batch size or just turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your example, comma is being used during the rendering, not the ordering.

examine the sql generated by each of your chained scope methods to resolve the ordering.

see also [Limit not working as expected in Rails3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776879/limit-not-working-as-expected-in-rails3)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but for anyone else with the same issue then I've found all you need to do is append '.all' to the variable/query, e.g.

```
render :csv => @inventory_items.all
```

OP was tagged as 3.2, but I can only validate this as working in 4.0